# Looping over data and creating individual figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looping over a list of names of different molecules and trying to generate individual figs for each of them. But for each successive molecule the new figures have all the previous data on as well. I've printed the data after I've gathered it and for each loop it's showing the correct amount. Here's my full code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mols = ["P_Z1", "P_Z2", "TT_Z1", "TT_Z2", "TP_Z1", "TP_Z2"]


for mol in mols:
    en = []
    den = []
    with open (mol+"clustered.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            e = line.strip().split()[1]
            en.append(e)
    with open (mol+"densities.txt") as g:
        for line in g:
            d = line.strip()
            den.append(d)
    data = zip(en,den)
    print data
    for energy, density in data:
        plt.xlabel("Density g/cubic cm")
        plt.ylabel("Energy kJ/mol")
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.spines["right"].set_color('none')
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        ax.spines["bottom"].set_color('none')
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
        ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('black')
        ax.xaxis.label.set_color('black')
        ax.yaxis.label.set_color('black')
        ax.tick_params(colors='black')
        plt.plot(density, energy, "ro")
        plt.savefig(mol+".png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=200, transparent=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the more OOP approach using figures and subplots. For example,

```
for mol in mols:
    for energy, density in data:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.addsubplot(111)
        ax.plot(density, energy, 'ro')

        ax.set_xlabel(...)
        ax.set_ylabel(...)
        [a.label.set_color('black') for a in (ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis)]
        # more spines and axis tinkering


        fig.savefig(mol+".png")
```

This way, you create a new figure for each energy/density plot.

**Edit:**

An even better alternative is to create the figure and axis outside the loop and just clear the loop before each plot. Thanks @Rutger Kassies

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.addsubplot(111)
for mol in mols:
    for energy, density in data:
        ax.cla() # or ax.clear()
        ax.plot(density, energy, 'ro')

        ax.set_xlabel(...)
        ax.set_ylabel(...)
        [a.label.set_color('black') for a in (ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis)]
        # more spines and axis tinkering

        fig.savefig(mol+".png")
```

**Edit2:**

Updating with @tcaswell's suggestions.

```
# Create the figure and subplot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.addsubplot(111)

# Tinker with labels and spines
ax.set_xlabel(...)
ax.set_ylabel(...)
[a.label.set_color('black') for a in (ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis)]
...

# Plot data and save figures
for mol in mols:
    for energy, density in data:
        ax.cla() # or ax.clear()
        p, = ax.plot(density, energy, 'ro')

        fig.savefig(mol+".png")
        p.remove() # removes specific plot from figure
```

Note that this will only render one density/energy line per figure. If you want to have multiple lines per figure, do something like

```
# same preamble
for mol in mols:
    lines = []
    for energy, density in data:
        ax.cla() # or ax.clear()
        p, = ax.plot(density, energy, 'ro')
        lines.append(p)

        fig.savefig(mol+".png")
    [p.remove() for p in lines]
```

Comment: I would start with trying a version where you create the `fig` and `ax` outside the loop and simply clear the axes at the end of each run with `ax.cla()`. That should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks this certainly seems to be working in creating the seperate figures except now I'm getting only the first point plotted, any idea what could be causing this? I can see the axes changing to reflect the data but only the first point. Also why didn't my first attempt work?

Comment: Your first attempt didn't work because you only created on `Axes` object using `plt.plot`. Each subsequent call to `plt.plot` plots the new data on the same `Axes` with the old data. Thus, with multiple calls to `plt.plot`, you get many plots on top of one another. Here, we're either creating a new `Axes` object for each iteration, or clearing the `Axes` object each iteration.

Comment: As for only plotting the first point, I'm not sure. You need to load the data in the same fashion in the `for mol in mols` loop. Make sure the density/energy lists are the correct size. Also, it may help if you change the data from strings to ints/floats. You can do this easily using `en/den = map(int/float, en/den)`.

Comment: can can do even better if you do all of the spine tweakinging outside of the loop, keep track of the artists you add in the loop and then remove _just_ those after you save (`ln, = plot(...); ... ; ln.remove()`

Comment: In both of the examples above the ax.clear and add subplot are right at the start of looping over the date so it gets cleared/overwritten each time I think. I moved the ax.clear outside of the data loop and that worked fine.

Edit: Just saw your fresh edit I think we both solved the problem in different ways