# how do i overwrite plot for iterative in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, iteration, pde

i want to plot a 1D Heat Diffusion with implicit PDE. here is the problem [Heat Diffusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtAw8.png). [here's the PDE equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i68A9.png).
my code is fine but it creates a new figure for each iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 0.05  #length
n = 5 #number of segment
T0 = 20  #initial temperature
T1s = 100 #boundary condition in segment 0
T2s = 25 #boundary condition in segment 5
dx = L/n #delta x
alpha = 0.000014129 #heat coeff
t_final = 9  
dt = 3

x = np.linspace(0, L, n+1)

T = np.ones(n+1)*T0 #array of Temperature initial condition
dTdt = np.empty(n+1) #dTdt delta T /delta t

t = np.arange(0, t_final, dt)

for j in range(1,len(t)+1):
    for i in range(1, n):
        dTdt[i] = alpha*(T[i+1]-2*T[i]+T[i-1])/dx**2   #PDE iterative function for segment i
    dTdt[0] = alpha*(T[1]-2*T[0]+T1s)/dx**2       
    dTdt[n-1] = alpha*(T[n-2]-2*T[n-1]+T2s)/dx**2    
    T = T + dTdt*dt
    T[0]=T1s
    T[5]=T2s
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x,T)
    plt.axis([-0.01, L+0.01, 0, 120])
    plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature (C)')
    plt.show()
```

i've added plt.ion() and plt.pause() but it didnt work. i also tried [similar PDE plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053077/looping-over-data-and-creating-individual-figures). but didnt work for me either. also is it possible to give each plot a different color and label in the figure?
any suggestion would help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the figure instance before the loop and add the figures + labels in the loop as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 0.05  #length
n = 5 #number of segment
T0 = 20  #initial temperature
T1s = 100 #boundary condition in segment 0
T2s = 25 #boundary condition in segment 5
dx = L/n #delta x
alpha = 0.000014129 #heat coeff
t_final = 9  
dt = 3

x = np.linspace(0, L, n+1)

T = np.ones(n+1)*T0 #array of Temperature initial condition
dTdt = np.empty(n+1) #dTdt delta T /delta t

t = np.arange(0, t_final, dt)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
for j in range(1,len(t)+1):
    for i in range(1, n):
        dTdt[i] = alpha*(T[i+1]-2*T[i]+T[i-1])/dx**2   #PDE iterative function for segment i
    dTdt[0] = alpha*(T[1]-2*T[0]+T1s)/dx**2       
    dTdt[n-1] = alpha*(T[n-2]-2*T[n-1]+T2s)/dx**2    
    T = T + dTdt*dt
    T[0]=T1s
    T[5]=T2s
    ax.plot(x,T,label = 'Iteration' + ' ' + str(j))
    
ax.legend()
ax.axis([-0.01, L+0.01, 0, 120])
ax.set_xlabel('Distance (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (C)');
```

Comment: ah i see. works perfect !.  but do you know why the plt.ion() and plt.pause() which i see a lot of people suggesting didnt work on me? how would i implement it?

Comment: Sadly, I have no experience with plt.pause or plit.ion but it seems like it's helpful for different applications than you need for this script. If my answer was the one you are looking for then please mark it as accepted with the tick symbol :).